# twitter-bootstrap carousel nav and content are not synchronized when autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I found a snippet for twitter-bootstrap to make a carousel with tabbed navigation.
Everything works fine except the "autoplay".

I want the carousel to slide by itself, so I specified a time interval for the carousel with `data-interval="1000"`

Problem: the carousel navigation tabs are not synchronized with the slides. The slides are animating as expected but the tab stays the same.

**Is there a clean way to make the tabs change in sync with the slides?**

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/35DGj/

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `'slid.bs.carousel'` event.

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/35DGj/1/

**JS** :

```
$(document).ready(function(ev){
    $('#custom_carousel .controls a').on('click',function(){
        $('#custom_carousel .controls li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
    });
    $('#custom_carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel',function(){
            var j = $('.carousel-inner .item.active').index();
            $('.controls .nav li').removeClass('active').eq(j).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

**SpidrJeru Solution :
EDIT**

*alternative solution*:

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(ev){
    $('#custom_carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
      $('#custom_carousel .controls li.active').removeClass('active');
      $('#custom_carousel .controls li:eq('+$(evt.relatedTarget).index()+')').addClass('active');
    })
});
```

*both solutions result in the exact same effect.*

Comment: This worked! Thanks mate. Sorry I don't have enough rep to pat you on the back :(

Comment: TheLittlePig solution worked like a charm, but I ended up using an alternative solution (in an EDIT above). It just felt a bit cleaner to me.